# Use value from dependency chart in child

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm writing a helm chart by making use of a dependency chart available in a chart repository.
Below is my Chart.yaml

```
appVersion: "1.2"
description: Helm chart for installation and maintenance of Test charts.
name: child-chart
version: 0.2.0

dependencies:
- name: parent-chart
  version: 1.0.9
  repository: https://testrepo.com/
  enter code here
```

The values.yaml of my parent-chart is having the below entry

```
testboard:
  enabled: true
  replicaCount: "1"
  appName: "test-operator"
```

I tried to use this name in my child chart by making use of {{.Values.testboard.appName}}, but this value is coming as **null**. When I gave {{.Values.parent-chart.testboard.appName}} it is failing with an error bad character U+002D '-'

How I should modify my helm template to get the correct values from my dependency chart

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to point out that *usually* we refer to *child* charts as the ones our *parent* chart depends on. To be more clearer, let's call those [subcharts](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/)

To answer your question, if you have something like this in the subchart `values.yaml`:

```yaml
testboard:
  appName: something
```

this in the parent chart:

```yaml
dependencies:
- name: subchart
  version: x.x.x
  repository: https://does-not-matter
  alias: alias-for-subchart # << this is optional!
```

you can override `testboard.appName` from the parent chart like this:

```yaml
alias-for-subchart:
  testboard:
    appName: something-else
```

if you provide an alias or

```yaml
subchart:
  testboard:
    appName: something-else
```

if you don't.

More explanations in the linked documentation.

Comment: My question is how to use the values from the sub chart if I'm not declaring any value in the parent-chart ??. When I use it like this {{.Values.testboard.appName}} the value is coming as null

Comment: You haven't set default values in values.yaml file in the subchart. If you follow the example I gave it should end up being “something”.